# PowerMock Constructor mock isn't working

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock

I have mocked a constructor using PowerMock.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SubjectClass.class)
class SomeClassTest {
    @Mock
    SubjectClass subjectObject;
    @InjectMock
    SomeClass someObject;
    ...
    @Test
    public void testMethod_inp_exp() throws Exception {
        PowerMock.whenNew(SubjectClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(subjectObject);
        when(subjectObject.subjectMethod(someParameters).thenReturn(null);
        assertThat(someObject.someMethod(someOtherParam).isEqualTo(someCondition);
    }
}
```

Isn't this enough to mock constructor? Is there anything missing.

Because, I have verified the code using, `Mockito.mockingDetails(subjectObject).isMock()` in the someMethod where it is called and I am getting `false`.

Comment: could you post the complete code so that I can test it.

Comment: It is proprietary code. What do you specifically need? What do you suspect might have some discrepancy. I'll add that code in abstract variable names.

Comment: It seems no problem with your code, try this: @PrepareForTest({SubjectClass.class, SomeClass.class})

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects) the class instantiating your `mocked class` must be prepared for test, aka `SomeClass`

Comment: Oh! Okay. So, the `@PrepareForTest(SubjectClass.class)` is used for Mocking static methods of SubjectClass, probably?

Comment: @Morfic It has worked. Thanks. You could write it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Yes, for static methods, you need to ["_prepare_" the class that contains those methods](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects) explicitly state that in order to mock constructors you should:

> Use `PowerMockito.whenNew`, e.g.
>
> ```
> whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new IOException("error message"));
> ```
>
> Note that you must prepare the class creating the new instance of
>   `MyClass` for test, not the `MyClass` itself. E.g. if the class doing new
>   `MyClass()` is called `X` then you'd have to do `@PrepareForTest(X.class)`
>   in order for `whenNew` to work:
>
> ```
> @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
> @PrepareForTest(X.class)
> public class XTest {
>         @Test
>         public void test() {
>                 whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new  IOException("error message"));
>
>                 X x = new X();
>                 x.y(); // y is the method doing "new MyClass()"
>
>                 ..
>         }
> }
> ```

So in your case you'd need to replace `@PrepareForTest(SubjectClass.class)` with `@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)`

Answer (score -1):

```
SubjectClass subjectClassMock=EasyMock.createNiceMock(SubjectClass.class);
PowerMock.expectNew(SubjectClass.class,<your arguments for constructor>).andReturn(subjectClassMock);
```

Make sure to add both SubjectClass and SomeClass in your @PrepareForTest and do a PowerMock.replayAll();

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to what I did.